# unknown column 'title' in field list Joomla Custom Component

Tags: mysql, joomla, custom-component

In my edit view, right after clicking save, an error shows:

```
Save failed with the following error: Unknown column 'title' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO `airx5_fields_` (`id`,`reportid`,`name`,`description`,`schema_name`,`table_name`,`column_name`,`holdout`,`title`) VALUES ('0','1','2345678','fgfhhhf','hgsfsb','geg','ergser','serg','')
```

I have no title field in my fields_ table. and I also did not write the code for inserting, i just added the toolbar for saving. this is getting me frustrated.

Comment: Looks like your table has no column `title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the statement in my prepareTable function :

```
//$table->title = htmlspecialchars_decode($table->title,
//  ENT_QUOTES);
```

turns out this was the one that added the title field in the table loaded from the model.

Answer (score -1):

At first be sure that which function save the submitted value. It may at table class or at model class. It may check "title" value before insertion.